# Testing a component that uses the ember-data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the best way to test a component that has injected the ember-data store via `store : Ember.inject.service()`?  I can get this working with an acceptance test but I would rather use a unit test for this component.

I need to be able to create sample ember-data models, mock the responses of `this.store.query` etc.

As an example, in the following selections is an `{async : true}` ember data relationship.

```
  //selection might or might not be passed
  if(selection && selection.get('id')) {
    //if the selection has an id, we can assume that it is should be resolved.
    this.get('store').findRecord('task', selection.get('id')).then((model) => {
      //... do something to the state of the compoent (the result of this needs to be tested and can't be mocked out."
  });
```

I need to way of creating an ember-data `selection` object and an async `promise`, then I need some way of creating an ember-data `store` and getting the `findRecord()` method to return the correct model.  I then need to get the `.then()` function to correctly pass this to the callback.

I have tried mocking out the `store` but get stuck at the .then function because I want it to execute the actual code not a mocked out version of it.

Comment: The basic setup is register the store with the resolver manually and any model(s) required. If you haven't done this you might look at a simple helper (something like this) https://github.com/toranb/writing-your-own-identity-map/blob/master/tests/unit/store-test.js#L11